# Compare column of a table with images in a folder on the server - VB.NET / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

In my Product Registration form, I have a Photo button to show the product photo in a pictubox1.

When the user clicks the photo button, the code will make a comparison between the `prdCod` column of the `Products` table and the `filename` of the image in the `Photo` folder on the server, and when found, it will show the corresponding image in `picturebox1`.

Photo button, execute the commands below:

```
Private Sub btnPhoto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPhoto.Click
        
        Dim IdProduto As String = prdCod   ** column in Products table that will be used for the search image in the Photos folder

        If File.Exists("\\server\cmg\projects\Photos" & IdProduto) Then   ** Search the image from the Photos folder on the server
           PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("\\server\cmg\projects\Photos" & IdProduto)
        End If
    End Sub
```

On the line

```
If File.Exists("\\server\cmg\projects\Photos" & IdProduto)
```

I have 2 problems:

- The image's filetype is being read in the comparison with the prdCod and I need to compare only the filename of the image for it to work;
- When the image's filename has leading zeros, the comparison doesn't work either.

**Note #1**: these images will not be saved in the `Products` table, they will already be in the `Photos` folder on the server and are only for being shown in `picturebox1`.

**Note #2**: the filenames of the images in the `Photos` folder will always be numbers and will never be repeated, ex.:\

```
    1.png, 2.png, 3.bmp, 4.jpg, 5.bmp, 6.jpeg...
```

How do I compare only the image filename from the `Photos` folder, without the filetype, and also ignoring the leading zeros?

Comment: Why not store the file name in the database? This loose collation between the file name and the ProductId seems strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the GetFiles method and use a wildcard for the extension.

```
Private Sub AddImageIfExists(idProduto As String)
    Dim folder As New DirectoryInfo("\\server\cmg\projects\Photos")
    If folder.Exists Then
        Dim file = folder.GetFiles($"{idProduto}.*").FirstOrDefault
        If file IsNot Nothing Then
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(file.FullName)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

That will add the photo if present.

To call the method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim IdProduto As String = prdCod
    AddImageIfExists(IdProduto)
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case, I would have to put the Private Sub that you posted, inside the Button's Private sub, eg:
Private Sub btnPhoto...
      Private Sub AddImageIfExists...

      End Sub
End Sub
that is, can I put a Private Sub inside another Private Sub?

Comment: I've just changed the answer to include a call.

Comment: I have a question, the prdCod (Table field) does not have a filetype, only the images have a filetype... will the search be carried out correctly in the `folder.GetFiles($"{Productid}.*")` command?. .I was in doubt about this command!

Comment: That is the point of the wildcard *. It ignores the the file type and just uses the name.

Comment: in the `Dim ProductId As String = prdCod` command the prdCod parameter should not be enclosed in double quotes, eg. `"prdCod"`?

Comment: I assume `prdCod` is a field outside of the method. There is no actual need to create the `IdProduto` field as it is not modified. You just pass `prdCod` straight into method.
Regarding quotes, no it doesn't need them.

Comment: Ok, I'll run the tests here, thanks.

Comment: Visual studio shows the error messages: "Exists" is not a member of "String" and "GetFiles" is not a member of "String", in the commands `folder.Exists` and `folder.GetFiles`?

Comment: I created the Photos folder in the Project and used the command
`Dim folder As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Photos"` to define the folder path. Could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to that. You basically have to iterate through all files in the folder, use e.g. [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension?view=net-7.0#system-io-path-getfilenamewithoutextension(system-readonlyspan((system-char)))) and remove leading zeros from that, before you do your comparison.

A better way ofc. would be to redesign the workflow and store the corresponding real filename (or even the fully qualified filename) along with the product code.

Comment: The database administrator does not want anything to be recorded in the database, not even the image path. Displaying the image in picturebox1 would only be for the user to see the product image.